# How do I incorporate set() into a character count function?

Tags: python, function, collections, set, counter

I'm trying to write a function that will count the number of characters in a given string, as well as the percentage of the string that is each character. I've gotten the function to work, but I'm wondering if there's a way to incorporate set() into the function.

```
def freq_and_perc(txt):
    txt_sort = sorted(txt)
    txt_count = Counter(txt_sort)
    for char in txt_count:
        print(f"'{char}': Count of {txt_count[char]} and Percentage of {txt_count[char]/len(txt_count):.1%}")
```

Comment: If you're using Counter, there's no real reason to use set

Comment: Also, there's no reason to sort the entirety of the text before using counter

Comment: Also, you should be dividing by `txt_count.total()` instead of `len(txt_count)`

Comment: @BenGrossmann or *len(txt)* which should be checked early in the function for zero

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of your function that uses set and the builtin str.count method.

```
def freq_and_perc(txt):
    L = len(txt)
    for char in sorted(set(txt)):
        ct = txt.count(char)
        print(f"'{char}': Count of {ct} and Percentage of {ct/L:.1%}")
```

For example, `freq_and_perc('abbbccd')` yields

```
'a': Count of 1 and Percentage of 14.3%
'b': Count of 3 and Percentage of 42.9%
'c': Count of 2 and Percentage of 28.6%
'd': Count of 1 and Percentage of 14.3%
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to sort the letters you might as well use groupby and no other intermediate data structure:

```
from itertools import groupby

def freq_and_perc(txt):
    for c,(*g,) in groupby(sorted(txt)):
        print(f"'{c}': Count of {len(g)} and Percentage of {len(g)/len(txt):.1%}")


freq_and_perc('banana')

'a': Count of 3 and Percentage of 50.0%
'b': Count of 1 and Percentage of 16.7%
'n': Count of 2 and Percentage of 33.3%
```